# how to group photos with similar faces together

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, recommendation-engine, face-recognition

In most face recognition SDK, it only provides two major functions

1. detecting faces and extracting templates from photos, this is called detection.
2. comparing two templates and returning the similar score, this is called recognition.

However, beyond those two functions, what I am looking for is an algorithm or SDK for grouping photos with similar faces together, e.g. based on similar scores.

Thanks

Comment: Do you already have similarity scores? Or are you asking about how to define a similarity score?

Comment: @bjoernz Assuming similarity scores are existed, since most SDKs provide face template comparing function.

Comment: I've expanded my answer with pseudo-code and an example data set, I believe it should work on unknown faces as well, as the comparisons are done on the extracted templates, not on any predetermined measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, perform step 1 to extract the templates, then compare each template with all the others  by applying step two on all the possible pairs, obtaining their similarity scores.

Sort the matches based on this similarity score, decide on a threshold and group together those templates that exceed it.

Take, for instance, the following case:

**Ten templates:** A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J.
**Scores between:** 0 and 100.
**Similarity threshold:** 80.

**Similarity table:**

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
A  100 85  8   0   1   50  55  88  90  10

B  85  100 5   30  99  60  15  23  8   2 

C  8   5   100 60  16  80  29  33  5   8

D  0   30  60  100 50  50  34  18  2   66

E  1   99  16  50  100 8   3   2   19  6

F  50  60  80  50  8   100 20  55  13  90

G  55  15  29  34  3   20  100 51  57  16

H  88  23  33  18  2   55  51  100 8   0

I  90  8   5   2   19  13  57  8   100 3

J  10  2   8   66  6   90  16  0   3   100
```

**Sorted matches list:**

AI 90
FJ 90
BE 99
AH 88
AB 85
CF 80
-------  <-- **Threshold cutoff line**
DJ 66
.......

Iterate through the list until the threshold cutoff point, where the values no longer exceed it, maintain a full templates set and association sets for each template, obtaining the final groups:

```
// Empty initial full templates set
fullSet = {};

// Iterate through the pairs list
foreach (templatePair : pairList)
{
  // If the full set contains the first template from the pair
  if (fullSet.contains(templatePair.first))
  {
     // Add the second template to its group
     templatePair.first.addTemplateToGroup(templatePair.second);

     // If the full set also contains the second template
     if (fullSet.contains(templatePair.second))
     {
        // The second template is removed from the full set
        fullSet.remove(templatePair.second);

        // The second template's group is added to the first template's group
        templatePair.first.addGroupToGroup(templatePair.second.group);
     }
  }
  else
  {
    // If the full set contains only the second template from the pair
    if (fullSet.contains(templatePair.second))
    {
      // Add the first template to its group
      templatePair.second.addTemplateToGroup(templatePair.first);
    }
  }
  else
  {
     // If none of the templates are present in the full set, add the first one
     // to the full set and the second one to the first one's group
     fullSet.add(templatePair.first);
     templatePair.first.addTemplateToGroup(templatePair.second);
  } 
}
```

**Execution details on the list:**

```
AI: fullSet.add(A); A.addTemplateToGroup(I);
FJ: fullSet.add(F); F.addTemplateToGroup(J);
BE: fullSet.add(B); B.addTemplateToGroup(E);
AH: A.addTemplateToGroup(H);
AB: A.addTemplateToGroup(B); fullSet.remove(B); A.addGroupToGroup(B.group);
CF: C.addTemplateToGroup(F);
```

In the end, you end up with the following similarity groups:

```
A - I, H, B, E
C - F, J
```

Comment: If you have a database of known faces, then it is right. however, I am grouping unknown faces based on similarity scores.

Comment: Ah, right, it's greedy algorithm. it's variant of kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: I have implemented face recognition using OpenCV lib..now I want to group photos with similar faces together..is the above answer in github or can someone provide me a link..I want to achieve something like "people" section of "google photos" app

Comment: Microsoft Cognitive Servcies Face API-It offers face detection,recognition,grouping,verification,similar face searching,etc

Comment: Can i have the java implementation of your answer. Also as i was reading more about face clustering i read about nearing neighbours and rank order hierarchy to cluster similar faces. I would like to know in detail please. At the moment i have faces detected and a similarity score with each detected with the others.